# get current spec name and status in jasmine2 in protractor

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I found jasmine.getEnv().currentSpec.description returns the name of the spec in the Jasmine1 version but doesn't work when switching to jasmine2 framework with protractor.

In my scenario I would like to capture screenshot for failure with spec name in after Each(). I am not sure how could I achieve this with jasmine2.

I know there is a package "protractor-html-screenshot-reporter" which can provide you the screenshot for failures. but I want to use the coding part here.

Hope you can help me to get a workaround for the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading correctly you want to have your spec name in your screenshot. If that's the case check the path builder section of the "protractor-html-screenshot-reporter" page on [github](https://github.com/jintoppy/protractor-html-screenshot-reporter).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, What I am trying here is getting the name of description block, Spec name and spec status in AfterEach and then creating the screenshot with spec name if spec got failed. Hope its understood now.